# What is the red and white circle that appears when I left click?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

When I click with the left mouse button, a white and red circular scope-target-looking-pointer moves to the location of the click. I can't make any sense of it and would like to find it in the manual. What is it called?

Comment: It is the 3D cursor, at this position new objects will be created; try 'Shift'-'A'

Comment: @stacker: thanks, that answers my question and is helpful too.